# iPad Safari ignores margins when flex item gets too large

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a few flex containers with 3 flex-items each. The first two flex-items have a `margin-right`, which spaces them from each other and from the third item. The first two items are always short (and constant width, in this case), and the third item has a variable width (can get long enough to wrap).

**[Here's an example (looks fine in Chrome, not so much on iPad)](https://jsfiddle.net/22frjv5x/2/)**

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.one, .two {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="one">hey</span>
    <span class="two">ho</span>
    <span class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="one">hey</span>
    <span class="two">ho</span>
    <span class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate molestias dolore in, nam neque facilis nulla eum beatae, excepturi fugiat.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="one">hey</span>
    <span class="two">ho</span>
    <span class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works well in nearly all browsers (I left out the -ms- prefixes because they're irrelevant to this issue), but in iPad's Safari (specifically, iPad Air 2 running Safari 8, maybe others), the margins get completely ignored when the third item is trying to grow larger, and the first two items get smooshed together.

---

### Expected

[image: Expected]

---

### Actual

[image: Actual]

---

This smells awfully like a bug in Safari, but I couldn't find any bug report or discussion about this online. It behaves as expected in pretty much every other browser. I've tried fiddling with pretty much all of the `flex-` properties, to no avail.

I'm looking first and foremost for a workaround, then also for an explanation on why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-webkit-flex: 1;` to the `.three` class. This tells the parent container that this element is flexible. ;-)

Comment: For future reference. IE11 apparently doesn't like `flex: 1`, so `flex: 1 0 auto` works well as a replacement.